# Write a sql query to get total fees paid by each student?

Tags: mysql, sql

. Given Table: Student_fees

| Names | Fees_Paid |
| --- | --- |
| Rajesh | 3000 |
| Sameer | 5000 |
| Shaila | 8000 |
| Sameer | 2000 |
| Rajesh | 2500 |

Expected Output:

| Name | Fees_Paid |
| --- | --- |
| Rajesh | 5500 |
| Sameer | 7000 |
| Shaila | 8000 |

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Comment: That's simple SUM with GROUP BY.

Comment: Hi - for all questions (but even more so for homework questions) you are expected to show some effort solving the problem yourself. Please update the question to show the SQL you've managed to write yourself and then ask a specific question about an issue you are facing

Answer (score 1):

You can use **GROUP BY** clause to get the result.

Following is the query.

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Fees_Paid) as Fees_Paid FROM Student_fees GROUP BY Name;
```